# Office Add-in / Overlay Region on top of the Ribbonbar

Tags: c#, vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbon

I want to create a custom Tab for Outlook's Ribbonbar.

I immediately ditched the thought of creating a true Ribbonbar with the standard controls because I know that it is severely limited. No custom controls, almost none of the well-known events which are available for the same controls in other projects, no chance for a different design or layout inside the ribbon, etc.

I made a Region and filled it with my custom WPF controls.
The region works fine, but here's the problem:

1. I want to have a custom Tab in the Ribbon ("MyTab")
2. When I click on the Tab, I want to display my Region where the  Ribboncontrols would be so that it looks like my Region is a Ribbonbar.

The height of the Ribbonbar is fixed and you can't change it AFAIK.
Is there any way to overlay my Region on top of the Ribbonbar?
It doesn't matter if it involves lots of work. I have to do it and I want to learn how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hearing here and everywhere else that what I wanted to do was indeed impossible, I came up with a workaround. I decided that if I can't make it work with the tools I'm supposed to use, I'll just improvise. Here's a short explanation if someone else ever needs to make a highly customized Ribbonbar:

1. Make a ribbontab with the RibbonUI. So far so good.
2. Create a borderless Dialog with a height of 92px (so that it fits
   inside the ribbon)
3. Put whatever customcontrols you want on that dialog (WPF controls
   need to be inside an ElementHost)
4. Download the "MouseKeyHook" NuGet Package and add event Handler for
   MouseClick.
5. Find out the position of your tab (use the Inspector x and y
   corrdinates) and do a simple IF statement to check if the user
   actually clicks inside the bounds of your tab (don't forget to check
   for both X and Y). When he does, just make a Dialog.Show().
6. Use the MouseMove event to resize AND reposition the dialog
   dynamically. If you don't do that, the dialog with stay in place
   when the user moves the Inspector.

...and so on. You also have to handle the dialog's behaviour when min/maximizing and closing. It's a lot of work but the Illusion is almost perfect. It looks like a real Ribbontab and you can do whatever you want inside of it. Give it a background image, draw a graph, open a browser.... :D

Answer (score 1):

You may consider placing your custom controls right under the ribbon bar. VSTO (nor Outlook form regions) doesn't provide any layout for that, but you can use Windows API for subsclassing Outlook windows. See [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) for more information and sample code. Or just use [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php), they provide the TopSubpane layout.

The Fluent UI provides a predefined set of controls and doesn't allow doing anything with the ribbon itself. Read more about the Ribbon UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I already placed my Region in the the TopSubpane. I really need to place it on top of the ribbon, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot overlay a region on top of a ribbon or any other control using any API exposed by Outlook.